# cakePHP build a select box from custom array

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, components, formhelper

So we have a variety of search pages each with different search criteria, so I decided to write a component which will get parameters passed to it from the controller, collect the neccesary data and return an array which I could then set to be used within my view file to populate drop down boxes to filter the criteria.

I have managed to get everything write up to where I must use the cakePHP helper to build a dynamical select box. I am convinced that I am doing something wrong and if there is an easier way to do this and still keep it somewhat dynamic please assist where you can:

```
// COMPONENT METHOD:
 public function filterQueries($parameters) {

    // Get defaults from the user:
    $criteria = $parameters["custom"];
    $defaults = $parameters["defaults"];

    // Validate the defaults the user may want and assign them to the return array:
    if($defaults != "false") {
        foreach($defaults as $key => $value) {
            if(array_key_exists($value, $this->defaults)) {
                $this->returnArray["defaults"][$value] = $this->defaults[$value];
            }
        }
    }

    // Get all data for the custom requested form fields:
    if($criteria != false) {
        foreach($criteria as $model => $arguments) {
            $fields = $arguments["fields"];
            $conditions = $arguments["conditions"];
            $recursive = $arguments["recursive"];
            if(!in_array($model,$this->uses)) {
                $useModel = ClassRegistry::init($model);
            } else {
                $useModel = $this->$$model;
            }
            $array = $useModel->find("all",array("conditions" => $conditions, "fields" => $fields, "recursive" => $recursive));
            $this->returnArray["custom"][$model] = $array;
        }
    }

    return $this->returnArray;
}
```

The above function will get an array which breaks down either custom searches or defaults (not included above but it all works, it returns the array exactly as I would have expected it.

```
 // The code within my action to get the content from above:
// Load the Filters component to search data:
        $search = $this->Components->load("Filter");

        // Tell search what you want:
        $searchBoxes = array(
            "defaults" => array("statuses", "survey_type"),
            "custom" => array(
              "User" => array(
                  "fields" => array("User.id","User.first_name", "User.last_name"),
                  "conditions" => array("User.user_group_id" => "4f847c63-1840-446e-88be-3e4d29566cf0"),
                  "recursive" => -1
              )  
            )
        );

       $filterResults = $search->filterQueries($searchBoxes);
       $this->set("filters",$filterResults);
```

So now I get this multi-associative array within my view file (all still fine), but I want to now build example a drop down list of the users based on the array created above, but the outcome is nothing like what I expected:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id',
                        array(
                            "type" => "select",
                            "options" => $filters["custom"]["User"]
                        )
                     );
```

The HTML output is broken and displays it like this:

```
<option value="last_name">Doe</option>
<option value="first_name">Jihn</option>
<optgroup label="User"> </optgroup>
<optgroup label="1"> </optgroup>
<option value="last_name">Marilyn</option>
<option value="first_name">Monroe</option>
```

I acknowledge that I do not have a lot of cake experience but cannot understand how to just get the results to :

```
 <option value='USERID'>NAME</option> // Yes I know the names and surnames must be concatinated still
```

Any advise help or guidance on how to do it, and do it the right way, would greatly be appreciated :)

**VARDUMP ON $filters['custom']['users']**

```
  array
   0 => 
     array
       'User' => 
         array
            'id' => string '4f84840e-cda8-4704-8fdf-210729566cf0' (length=36)
            'first_name' => string 'Name' (length=4)
            'last_name' => string 'Surname' (length=11)
    1 => 
      array
        'User' => 
          array
            'id' => string '4f8488cb-53e0-4f72-af73-3de229566cf0' (length=36)
            'first_name' => string 'Name' (length=6)
            'last_name' => string 'Surname' (length=6)
```

Comment: What does a `var_dump($filters["custom"]["User"])` look like?

Comment: array
  0 => 
    array
      'User' => 
        array
          'id' => string '4f84840e-cda8-4704-8fdf-210729566cf0' (length=36)
          'first_name' => string 'NAME' (length=4)
          'last_name' => string 'SURNAME' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      'User' => 
        array
          'id' => string '4f8488cb-53e0-4f72-af73-3de229566cf0' (length=36)
          'first_name' => string 'NAME' (length=6)
          'last_name' => string 'SURNAME' (length=6) ..... It returns all the other users as well

Comment: Oh, can you edit your question it post it there.  Hard to read in the comments with no formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enhance your output by doing as follows:

1) for combining two fields of a table, you can use `"virtualfields"`  in the model, as follows: For example if you have the user model, you can define as follows:

```
 public $virtualFields = array(
  'full_name' => 'CONCAT(first_name, " ",last_name)'
 );
```

So now the "full_name" field will be got whenever you call the `find` method of the User model.

2) For getting the data from the table for a select box, you can use the `find('list')` method. For example for the User model if you need the `id,full_name (last and first name combined using the virtual fields)` of the table,it can be done as follows :

```
$this->User->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','full_name'),'conditions'=>$conditions))
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: The crux of this is the `list` parameter for the `find` method. This helps the form helper figure out what the value should be and what should be displayed.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess what you want to do is actually create another array with formatted options.

```
foreach ($filters["custom"]["User"] as $arr)
{
    $options[$arr['id']] = $arr['first_name'] . ' ' . $arr['last_name'];
}
```

then

```
echo $this->Form->select('user_id', $options);
```

Comment: Hey Jack, I see where you're going with this, and I am happy to do it this way, but would you advise me to do it this way or is there a more efficient way of doing what I am trying to achieve above?

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way since you need the options to be formatted in a specific way.  The CakePHP form->select uses the array key as the `name="value"` and the array value as the form text.  http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1430/select but your `$results` array from the find query returns a multidimensional array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
$result = Set::combine($filters["custom"]["User"], 

                       '{n}.User.id', // this is the value of select box

                         array(
                               '{0} {1}', 
                               '{n}.User.first_name', 
                               '{n}.User.last_name'
                              ) // this is the text of select box
                      );

pr($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

$this->form->input('inputname', array('label' => false, 'options' => array('Select optionstype','a','b'), 'class'=>array('form-a', 'b'), 'id' => 'bacid', 'style' => 'width:280px;','value'=>$abc['model']['array_attribute']));

Answer (score 0):

On cakePHP 3, I can't use "virtualFields" yet, but I can use as follows:

```php
//In PostsController
$users = $this->Posts->Users->find('list', 
['keyField'   => 'id', 
 'valueField' => 'full_name', //Don't forget to call concatened field here
 'conditions' => $conditions, 
 'order'      => $orderBy 
]);

//here the magic happens
$concat = $users->func()->concat(
['Users.first_name' => 'identifier', 
 ' ', 
 'Users.last_name' => 'identifier'
]);

//selecting fields
$users->select(['id', 'full_name' => $concat]);

//sending to view
$this->set('users', $users->toArray());
```

I hope this helps CakePHP 3 developers